# С глазами как блюдца

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

В известной сказке сравнительный оборот "как блюдца" обычно обособляется, но правильно ли это?

(1) Стоило ударить по кремню один раз — являлась собака с глазами, что чайные блюдца. А два раза ударит солдат — бежит к нему собака с глазами, как мельничные колёса.

(2) Собака с глазами, как блюдца, на старом, как мир, сундуке.

Также другие примеры:

(3) Почему японцы, узкоглазые по сути, в мультиках рисуют себя с глазами как блюдца?

(4) Глаза как блюдца, доверчивые

(5) Глаза огромные, как блюдца.

(6) Невысокий, а глаза, как блюдца.

В каких примерах оборот обособлен или не обособлен правильно и почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Выражение "глаза как блюдца" имеет значение "большие, огромные глаза". В этом значении устойчивое выражение, на мой взгляд,  оформляется без запятой.
Как только появляется другое значение (например, круглые) или выражение обретает иную структуру (появляется "лишнее" слово), запятая ставится.***

(1) Стоило ударить по кремню один раз — являлась собака с глазами, что *чайные* блюдца. А два раза ударит солдат — бежит к нему собака с глазами, как мельничные колёса.

(2) Собака с глазами как блюдца (*значение "большие"*) на старом, как мир, сундуке (*ироническое использование фразеологизма "старо как мир", но слово "старый" употреблено в прямом значении, "как мир" - сравнение*).

(3) Почему японцы, узкоглазые по сути, в мультиках рисуют себя с глазами, как блюдца (*круглыми*)?

(4)Глаза как блюдца (*несогласованное однородное определение или сказуемое, в зависимости от контекста предложения, значение "большие"*), доверчивые

(5) Глаза огромные, как блюдца (*сравнение имеет дополнительное значение меры, степени,  относится к слову "огромные"*).

(6) Невысокий, а глаза как блюдца (*сказуемое, значение "большие"*).

***Не рассчитываю на безоговорочное приятие ответа, готова к дискуссии.***

Comment: У Розенталя есть подобный пример: Небо как море ( как присоединяет сказуемое). Год, как жизнь( год подобен жизни, а не год есть жизнь). Так если, как отметила Екатерина, все зависит от смысла. Ср.: Небо, как море, бушует ( небо подобно морю бушует).

Comment: В четвертом примере, если обособить сравнительный оборот, исказится смысл. Ср.: Глаза,  как блюдца, доверчивые ( доверчивые, словно блюдца. Получается, такие же доверчивые, как блюдца). А смысл: большие, доверчивые глаза.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже в  качестве дискуссии

А. Решая вопрос об обособлении сравнительного оборота, мы обычно используем ОСОБЫЕ ПРАВИЛА, но правильно ли это? Другая точка зрения заключается  в том, что следует рассматривать  сравнительный  оборот как  член предложения и применять к нему ОБЩИЕ ПРАВИЛА, а не  ориентироваться только на его статус.

Б. Сравнительный оборот как член предложения (функции в предложении):

а) сравнительный оборот КАК АНАЛОГ СРАВНИТЕЛЬНОГО ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ; обособленное сравнение,  обычная схема: два предмета обладают одним признаком.

б) ИМЕННАЯ ЧАСТЬ СКАЗУЕМОГО (не обособляется);

в) НЕСОГЛАСОВАННОЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ (обособляется или не обособляется в зависимости от ситуации: структуры предложения, распространенности оборота).

В. Из приведенных ранее примеров

1)  Небо как море.  Именная часть сказуемого.

2)  Небо, как море,  бушует.  Обособленное сравнение, аналог сравнительного предложения; небо и море имеют один признак (бушуют).

3)  Год, как жизнь. Назывное предложение, распространенное сравнительным оборотом в качестве обособленного определения.

4)   Собака с глазами  как блюдца, На старом, как мир, сундуке.  Необособленное несогласованное определение. Обособлению оборота препятствует  расстановка тонических ударений, нет паузы.

5) Являлась собака с глазами, что чайные блюдца. Обособленное несогласованное определение. Оборот распространен, пауза возможна (с глазами, похожими на чайные блюдца).

6)  Почему японцы, узкоглазые по сути, в мультиках рисуют себя с глазами как блюдца? Необособленное несогласованное определение, паузы нет, ударение падает на оборот.

7)  Глаза огромные, как блюдца.  Обособленное сравнение, аналог сравнительного предложения; глаза и блюдца имеют один признак (огромные).

Comment: Вера, некоторые правила недостаточно разработаны. Здесь нужен не формальный подход. Один и тот же оборот может быть и частью сказуемого, и сравнительным оборот. Надо учитывать структуру, смысл. А в справочниках формальный подход. Наши с вами дискуссии не к чему. Если есть какие-нибудь предложения, можно обратиться в Институт русского языка. Хотя, мне кажется, там и слушать не захотят.

Comment: Всё правильно, наши правила формальные, но эти правила не должны мешать нам жить. Нам нужно СОСУЩЕСТВОВАТЬ с системой, то есть легко и быстро справляться с решением задачи и при этом оставаться в рамках правил. Человек с системой ни бороться, ни дискутировать однозначно не может, но может научиться противостоять ей. В теме сравнительных оборотов правила  противоречивы и неуклюжи, как нигде.

Comment: Поэтому лучшее решение - это не давать частные толкования каждому отдельному случаю, а привести их в простую и понятную систему, удобную в применении, как бы немного механизировать процесс, исключив тяжелый ручной труд.

Comment: Вера, а как вы это представляете?

Comment: Серж, так я в своем ответе такую схему представила: мы должны определить, каким членом предложения является сравнительный оборот,  входит ли он в основной состав предложения, или является обособленным членом.  Например: "Глаза огромные, как блюдца" . Екатерина дает частное описание: "сравнение имеет дополнительное значение меры, степени, относится к слову "огромные".

Comment: Но из него не следует со всей очевидностью необходимость обособления. И в то же время здесь обособление обязательно, так как признак назван два раза: глаза огромные,  глаза как блюдца. Здесь сравнительный оборот - это второе сказуемое (однородное или  уточняющее).