# Есть другой человек, с глазами, как звезды

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужна ли указанная запятая?
**Есть другой человек, с глазами(,) как звезды.**

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415996/%D0%A1-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0

Comment: Просмотрела я очень мельком дискуссию, интересное было обсуждение. Vera, вероятно, верно говорит об общем (неформальном) подходе к решению подобных задач, вот и мы тоже подойдем неформально, определив, какими семантическим оттенками отличаются варианты. Я назвала оба, а вы, Alex_ander, больше ориентируетесь на формальный признак "тесной связи". А какой  вариант прочтения предложения вам больше нравится чисто эстетически, какой более художественный?

Answer (score 1):

**Решение:**

Попробуем сравнить варианты с разной расстановкой ударения:

(1) *Есть другОй человек, с глазАми, **как звЁзды.***
(2) *Есть другОй человек, с глазами  **как звЁзды**.*

Хотя оба варианта возможны, но вариант (1)  выглядит  как более предпочтительный и художественный. В этом случае  определительный оборот представлен как  отдельное описание внешности героя: *с глазАми, **похожими на звЁзды.***

**Комментарий**

1. Правило

По Розенталю оборот «как звезды» имеет значение **уподобления** и в общем случае обособляется. Но в конкретном предложении  он может обособляться или не обособляться,  что зависит от структуры этого предложения (об этом Розенталь также говорит).

https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

Оборот часто встречается в речи, но фразеологических сочетаний  он не образует. Однозначно он не обособляется только самом простом предложении: *Глаза как звезды.* Все остальные случаи требуют **интонационно-структурного  анализа.**

2. Примеры:

Но кто же она? Эта девушка **с глазами, как звезды**? И чего хотят от него эти удивительные глаза?

Я люблю Эльфу, у нее глаза, **как звезды**, а волосы до колен.

Звезды смотрят на нас, у тебя глаза **как звезды**, я не могу с тобой расстаться.

Посмотрела бы ты на него: глаза **как звезды** светятся...

Из этих примеров видно, что обособление оборота зависит от структуры предложения и авторского решения.

Comment: _Дрова трещат, стреляют золотыми, **как звезды**, угольками._ Мне кажется, что об этом примере нельзя говорить "сравнительный оборот внутри другого обособленного оборота".

Comment: Я бы уверенно выбрал здесь вариант _без_ запятой, поскольку без сравнительного добавления смысл разрушается: "человек с глазами". Здесь имеет место пресловутая тесная связь, в примере же из Розенталя сравнительный оборот без таких проблем отбрасывается.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, убрала предложение.

Comment: Alex_ander, вы этот пример имеете в виду: «Вечер был как две капли воды похож на всякий другой вечер». Здесь грамматика другая (Розенталь подробно не указывает разницу).  Есть другОй человек, с глазами как звЁзды.  В этом случае оборот из описательного признака становится отличительным, главным для этого человека. Выглядит несколько манерно и излишне подчеркнуто. Так что автор может выбирать, что ему нравится больше, интонационно оба варианта возможны.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что пунктуация зависит от контекста: от того, что именно нам надо выделить, какой смысл подчеркнуть.

*Есть человек с глазами как щелочки. **Есть другой человек, с глазами как звезды.** Есть третий — с глазами как блюдца.*
В этом случае мы характеризуем (сравниваем) **людей** — только по одному "качеству", только по этой особенности.

**Есть другой человек — с глазами, как звезды.**
В этом случае, чтобы подчеркнуть уточняющее значение несогласованного определения (существительного с предлогом) и выделить сравнение, вместо первой запятой я бы поставила интонационное тире.

Вот, наверно, самые известные "глаза, как звезды" (У. Шекспир. Гамлет):

> А то бы
> От слов легчайших повести моей
> Зашлась душа твоя и кровь застыла,
> **Глаза, как звезды,** вышли из орбит
> И кудри отделились друг от друга,
> Поднявши дыбом каждый волосок,
> Как иглы на взбешенном дикобразе.

[Постановка запятой перед союзом КАК](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183#:%7E:text=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9A%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,2.)